# How to extract elements from from a 3D array efficiently?

Tags: matlab, indexing

Let's say `G = [1,2;3,4]` and `G(:,:,2) = [11, 22; 33, 44]`.

I want to output `[1,11]`. i.e [1,1] st elements of `G(:,:,1)` and `G(:,:,2)` in one command.

I tried using `G(1,1,[1 2])`but it is giving the following outputs

```
ans(:,:,1) =

     1
ans(:,:,2) =

    11
```

But I want output in this form i.e in one array `[1 ; 11]`.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Your question is kind of confusing. Since this is your first one, you may consider take a look at this tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

See [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to remove singleton dimensions:

```
G = [1,2;3,4];
G(:,:,2) = [11, 22; 33, 44];

A = G(1,1,[1 2]);
A = squeeze(A);
```

Returns

```
A =

     1
    11
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve your problem by [reshaping](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your matrix into the correct format that you need.

```
>> reshape(G(1, 1, :), length(G(1, 1, :)), 1)

ans =

     1
    11
```

---

Just incase you are unaware, in a matrix `:` can be used to represent every element along that dimension saving you effort.

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
G(1:size(G,1)*size(G,2):end)
```

which uses [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) and directly gives a vector.